# Material mat-select name attribute

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on some simple form converting it from bootstrap to Material.

Altough I am working with Angular 6, the form is posted old-style on submit (no use of angular forms)

```
<form method="post" action="http://api.example.com/submit" id="user_form">

   <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="name" name="username">
   </mat-form-field>


   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="user-type" name="usertype">
         <mat-option value="type1">type1</mat-option>
         <mat-option value="type2">type2</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>

   <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

For simplicity, I'd would like to keep it this way, and don't use any javascript on submiting this form (no template-driven form OR reactive form).

the `input` is working great with adding `name` attribute to the `imput` and when I POST the form (click on the submit button) it sent to server as expected.

as for the `mat-select`, this data isn't sent to server in the post data.
I guess that the former is native `input` where `mat-select` is a component.

Is there is a way to make this work? (again, without handling the form POST on the TS side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Just use the native `select` like this:

```
<select matNativeControl placeholder="user-type" name="usertype" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="type1">type1</option>
  <option value="type2">type2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to set `name` attribute to the `mat-select` element directly.

In order to achieve it you need to use a `[attr.name]` construction. In the end the code would look like this.

```html
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="user-type" [attr.name]="'usertype'">
         <mat-option value="type1">type1</mat-option>
         <mat-option value="type2">type2</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

Demo: [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/selector-name?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thanks! Using [attr.name] allows you to pass in a variable as well as a string.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't achieve that.

Unlike `input` field, `mat-select` is an angular component composed of `div` and `span`.

[image]

you can only send the its binded value.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching the same and solved this by binding a hidden input field. No need to write code-behind.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #matSelect placeholder="user-type">
     <mat-option value="type1">type1</mat-option>
     <mat-option value="type2">type2</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<input type="hidden" name="usertype" [value]="matSelect.value" />
```